# How to use the multicore option in vowpal wabbit

Tags: multicore, vowpalwabbit

I am running vowpal wabbit (ksvm option) on a single machine (8 core Macbook pro). How can I make it use all the 8 cores?

From the linked videos (videolectures.net) on the github page I see there is a `--thread-bits` option to control the number of threads but `vw --help` doesn't list this option so I guess It's not there any more in the latest version.

What is the right way to use the multicore capabilities of vowpal wobbit. I don't want to run it over multiple nodes but I am interested in using the multicore capabilities on a single machine.

Answer (score 2):

#### Is vowpal-wabbit "multi-core"?

Only partially. It uses 2 cores by default (using C++ std::thread):

- IO/Parsing thread: murmur-hash3 for hashing features, fast-atof for parsing numerics, & parse-example
- Learning thread (SGD predict, estimate-error & update loop)

None of these are making examples appear out-of-order as real-parallelization might do. Data examples are all processed sequentially but in a (short) parallel pipeline.

#### Disabling multi-threading (switch to single core):

Use the option: `--onethread`

So the overall answer to your question is that the present options don't let you parallelize beyond 2 cores.

#### Cluster mode aka all-reduce

As you mentioned, there's the cluster-mode which supports data-partitioning and processing each part on a separate node in a cluster.

#### `--thread-bits` ?

Grepping the (latest) source code, I can't find any reference to `--thread-bits`.